# Use raw $value in hasMany relationships in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, accessor, mutators

I have a class that looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use App\State;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Property
{
    /**
    * Connection state logs connected to property
    */
    public function states() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\State', 'property_ip', 'ip');
    }

    /**
     * Always force ips to be stored as numbers and shown as strings
     * 
     * 192.168.0.2 vs 3232235522
     */
    public function setIpAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['ip'] = ip2long($value);
    }
    public function getIpAttribute($value) {
        return long2ip($value);
    }
}
```

In the database, all IPs are stored as integers but they are always shown as strings. The problem is that the accessor `getIpAttribute()` converts ip to a string and then the hasMany relationship `states` tries to look up states by the text ip when it should be looking it up by the integer ip. If I kill the accessor, everything works, but then it shows the IPs as integers which is useless to an end user.

Is there a way to have a accessor like this but to still be able to join based on the value as it comes out of the database?

Comment: Would [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) be good for that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean accessor and not mutator. You should rewrite your accessor to use different name for example

```
public function getDottedIpAttribute($value) 
{
    return long2ip($value);
}
```

and now your relationship will work without any problem and to display IP in human readable format you can use `$property->dotted_ip` instead of `$property->ip` (obviously you can use better name than `dotted_ip` for human readable ip).

This gives you also benefit that you have both original and processed by `long2ip` values easily accessible so you can use any of them whenever you want.

Comment: I figured I could do something like this, or even `public function states() {return State::where('property_ip', ip2long($this->ip));}`. I was hoping to keep it a little cleaner.